# Child bone deforms when moving parent bone with copy rotation and mesh deform

Tags: modifiers, armature, parent

When I move the bone it deforms the children as well with the parent bone.
Here's a screenshot of what I mean,[image]
I have the copy rotation and mesh deform modifier on this mesh.
The copy rotation has an empty as the target.
Why does this keep happening?

Comment: Hello, it's not clear at all, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the blend file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=503r7XjY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/503r7XjY/)

Comment: both the mesh and the Mesh Deform cage have an Armature modifier, could you please explain what you're trying to do with this Mesh Deform?

Comment: I was using the Mesh Deform to move the mouth mesh around..It allows for the mesh to move without actually rotating the mouth keeping it in place.I hope I explained it right.